# Sort a list of pairs using sort Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a function (frequency) which that counts how many times each distinct value in a list occurs in that list. For example,

```
frequency "ababca"
```

should return:

```
[(3, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (1, 'c')].
```

This works fine but now I need to sort the list using the first element within the list of the list using this function.

```
results   :: [Party ] -> [(Int, Party)]
results  xs = ??? frequency (sort xs) ???
```

example of desired output:

```
[(1, "Green"), (2, "Red"), (3, "Blue")]
```

The above does not work, I have no idea what I can do.

using regular 'sort'

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Note you are using semicolons where Haskell uses commas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (sortBy)

results xs = sortBy (compare `on` fst) (frequency xs)

-- or, if you prefer
results xs = sort (frequency xs)
```

Links to documentation for [`on`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Function.html#v%3aon), [`sortBy`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3asortBy), [`compare`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3acompare), [`fst`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3afst).

The difference is that `sort` sorts in ascending order of the first element of each pair, breaking tie-breaks with the second elements of the pairs, while `` sortBy (compare `on` fst) `` explicitly only looks at the first element of each pair.

Comment: How can I use regular 'sort' to do the same as the above ?

Comment: You can use `(comparing fst)` instead of `(compare \`on\` fst)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you can only use `sort` and not `sortBy` (for some reason!) then you need to make sure that the items are of a type that is an instance of `Ord`. As it happens, all tuples (up to size 15) have `Ord` instances, provided that *all* the positions in the tuple also have `Ord` instances.

The example you give of `(1, "Green"), (2, "Red"), (3, "Blue")]` should sort fine (though reversed), since both `Int`  and `String` have `Ord` instances.

However, in the code snippet, you also mention a `Party` type without actually saying what it is. If it's not just an alias for something like String, you may have to define an `Ord` instance for it, to satisfy the built-in Ord instances for tuples.

You can have Haskell create instances for you, using `deriving` when you declare the type

```
 data Party = P1 | P2 | P3 | P4 -- e.g.
     deriving (Eq,Ord)
```

or declare it yourself:

```
 instance Ord Party where
     -- you don't care about the ordering of the party values
     compare a b = EQ
```

But, as dave4420 says, it's much better to just use `sortBy`, so I would do that unless you have a specific reason not to (ie it's a class assignment with restrictions).